# Unity 2d Dragging with right mouse button - rubber band issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my code to drag my 2d world with the right mouse button.
It drags fine, when i lick and hold the button, but once i let go it rubber bands back to where it was. (origin)

This is the code i use:

```
[SerializeField] private InputAction _mouseClick;

private Camera _mainCamera;
private bool _isDragging = false;
private Vector3 _origin;
private Vector3 _difference;

private void Awake()
{
_mainCamera = Camera.main;
}

private void Update()
{
if (!_isDragging)
    return;

_difference = GetMousePosition - _mainCamera.transform.position;
_mainCamera.transform.position = _origin - _difference;
}

private void OnEnable()
{
_mouseClick.Enable();
_mouseClick.started += _mouseClick_started;
_mouseClick.canceled += _mouseClick_canceled;
}
private void OnDisable()
{
_mouseClick.started -= _mouseClick_started;
_mouseClick.canceled -= _mouseClick_canceled;
_mouseClick.Disable();
}

private void _mouseClick_started(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
_origin = GetMousePosition;
_isDragging = true;
}

private void _mouseClick_canceled(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
_isDragging = false;
}

private Vector3 GetMousePosition => 
_mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Mouse.current.position.ReadValue());
```

On the unity side i add a very simple Right Mouse Button Action.
I am very new to unity, so prefer to have as much as possible in code as that makes more sense to me.

Comment: i would suggest throwing some debug statements in to see whats going on - do you have anything else that may effect its position?